# maven springboot test not running integration tests with specific datasource bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have been struggling for a couple of days with spring testing.
We are using maven-failsafe-plugin and using docker containers for our two specific databases.

But when we include the non-primary datasource configuration, no tests are run.

So config is (docker-maven-plugin sets the ip/host system properties for us):

```
metadata:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://${docker.mariadb.ip}:${docker.mariadb.port}/METADATA
    password: m_user
    username: m_pswd

reporting:
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:vertica://${docker.vertica.ip}:${docker.vertica.port}/REPORTING?allowMultiQueries=true
    username: v_user
    password: v_pswd
```

We have two database configuration classes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = {"com.company.application"}
)
public class MariadbConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "metadata.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties reportingDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "metadata.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties mariadbDataSourceProperties) {
        return (HikariDataSource) mariadbDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        ...
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionTemplate")
    public TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate(@Qualifier("transactionManager")
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }
}
```

And

```
@Configuration
public class VerticaConfiguration {

    @Bean("verticaDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "reporting.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties verticaDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "verticaDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "reporting.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource verticaDataSource() {
        return (HikariDataSource) verticaDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "verticaJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate verticaJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(verticaDataSource());
    }
}
```

So our test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("itest")
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MariadbConfiguration.class, VerticaConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest
public class ApplicationIT {

    @Autowired
    DataSource mariadb;

    @Qualifier("verticaDataSource")
    @Autowired
    DataSource vertica;
    
    @Test
    public void testApplicationLoaded() {}

}
```

So if we `mvn verify` this no tests are run

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2:integration-test (default) @ our-application ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

BUT if we change the `@ContextConfigutation` to not include vertica

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MariadbConfiguration.class})
```

Then the test runs (and fails with bean initiasation error as expected)

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2:integration-test (default) @ our-application ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
...
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.81 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.company.application.test.ApplicationIT
[ERROR] testApplicationLoaded  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: ...
...
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

If we change the `@ContextConfigutation` to not include mariadb

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={VerticaConfiguration.class})
```

Then no tests are run.

Just to be clear, I am not asking about the error.

The question is why does including the `VerticaConfiguration.class` mean no tests are run? Seems very weird. Application itself is fine, this is just a testing issue.

Versions:

- java: 8
- spring boot: 2.2.6
- spring framework: 5.2.5
- junit: 4.12

Part of our problem is we kind of inherited this project. So we use spring without properly understanding how it all hangs together.

Comment: Ok, have made some progress here. The application I am testing is made up of two maven modules (jars). If I move the `VerticaConfiguration` class from the application module into the library module then it works. But in real world, cannot do this, vertica is reporting application only. So my guess is having config class in child package of application, spring is somehow picking up application and that is messing with spring test? So guess I need to understand spring better

Comment: So this is so weird. I deleted everything from the application package except the `VerticaConfiguration` class and main class. But in the main class I removed all spring annotations and changed main method to be a `System.out.println`. But still appears that nothing is running at all. Something very odd going on here.