# SpringBootTest ClassNotFoundException error in integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I have been struggling with SpringBootTest for several days now. I initially posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71836098/maven-springboot-test-not-running-integration-tests-with-specific-datasource-bea). I have reduced it to a much simpler case.

I have a very simple app with a single service and an application class.
Service class:

```
package com.sodved.itestcase0.app.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AppService {

    public String getServiceName() {
        return this.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    }
}
```

Application:

```
package com.sodved.itestcase0.app;

imports...

@Slf4j
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass=true)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.sodved.itestcase0"})
public class Case0Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private AppService appService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Case0Application.class, args);
        log.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
        context.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("Application running...");
        log.info("App Service: {}", appService.getServiceName());
    }

}
```

That all runs fine:

```
spring-itest> java -jar case0/case0-app/target/case0-app-0.0.1-0-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
2022-04-21 12:23:53.589  INFO 65095 --- [           main] c.s.itestcase0.app.Case0Application      : Application running...
2022-04-21 12:23:53.589  INFO 65095 --- [           main] c.s.itestcase0.app.Case0Application      : App Service: com.sodved.itestcase0.app.service.AppService
```

But my integration test fail with a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Integration test context (if I use the Application class itself, no tests are run???):

```
package com.sodved.itestcase0.app.itest;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.sodved.itestcase0"})
public class DummyApplicationContext {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Dummy Context (Not sure if this should ever run)");
    }

}
```

Integration test class:

```
package com.sodved.itestcase0.app.itest;

import com.sodved.itestcase0.app.service.AppService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes=DummyApplicationContext.class)
public class IntegrationIT {

    @Autowired
    private AppService appService;

    @Test
    public void testApplicationLoaded() {
        log.info("Application loaded OK");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAppSerivce() {
        log.info("App Service: {}", appService.getServiceName());
    }

}
```

Tests fail:

```
spring-itest> mvn clean verify -P itest -pl case0 -am -amd
...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.sodved.itestcase0.app.itest.IntegrationIT
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.sodved.itestcase0.app.itest.IntegrationIT
[ERROR] com.sodved.itestcase0.app.itest.IntegrationIT  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/sodved/itestcase0/app/service/AppService;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sodved.itestcase0.app.service.AppService

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   IntegrationIT » NoClassDefFound Lcom/sodved/itestcase0/app/service/AppService;
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

So I assume this is a simple stuffup by me (something wrong in my pom.xml?).
Some other points I have noted:

- Only an issue for component classes defined in module being tested. It all works fine if the component class is from a dependency (see [case1 in github](https://github.com/sodved/spring-itest/tree/master/case1)).
- As stated above, if I use `Case0Application` as the SpringBootTest class, then no tests are run. That is why I created the dummy context. You can see this in the [case0-no-tests](https://github.com/sodved/spring-itest/tree/case0-no-tests) branch.

My example source code is available here: https://github.com/sodved/spring-itest

I've been banging my head against this for days. Read heaps of tutorials and manuals etc. It feels like a test config/classpath issue, but not sure if it's maven or spring boot where my mistake is. I cannot figure it out.

My real issue involves database containers etc, but this is the simplest case I could reproduce my issues with. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Edit SpringBootTest(classes=DummyApplicationContext) annotation  -> @SpringBootTest, basically remove the classess, currently it's loading DummyApplicationContext.class only.  alternatively you can add AppService.class in classes list.

Comment: My issue is the real case has dozens of repository and service classes which need testing. So I would rather not have to list them individually. What I want (and what the tutorials imply) is that all the services etc will be autowired for the testing, just like they are for the real app (which works fine).

I have tried many variations (e.g. put everything in same package and removed the `classes=` from `@SprintBootTest` but I get either the classNotFound error or no tests run at all.

Comment: try -> mvn clean  compile verify -P itest -pl case0 -am -amd

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know is that SpringBoot will automatically scan the @SpringBootApplication annotation for the relevant classes in the package and inject them into the container, or use the @scanBasepackages annotation to define the location of the custom scan, so your test class will load DummyApplicationContext class. Spring will help you to load the com sodved. Itestcase0. App. Itest child bag class, so led to can not find AppService, you can try to put the DummyApplicationCon Text class migrated to com. Sodved. Itestcase0. App package, and then see if there are any problems

Comment: My English is not good, I use translation software, please forgive me

Comment: Isn't [this line](https://github.com/sodved/spring-itest/blob/master/case0/case0-app/src/test/java/com/sodved/itestcase0/app/itest/DummyApplicationContext.java#L7) equivalent to `@ScanBasePackages`? Moving the dummy context into a different package made no differnence. And if I use a context from the `main` source tree, then no tests are run.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice that line of code. It's equal

Comment: Please wait a moment while I download your code to check

Comment: I have no problem here, you can try mvn clean or clear idea cache

Comment: I always `mvn clean` and just use cmdline, so no IDE cache to worry about. Have also cleard out my local `~/.m2/repository` just in case. So it is working for you when when you `mvn verify -P itest`? What version of maven do you have? (only thing I can imagine would be different). Tried switching to normal tests (surefire plugin) but still not working

Comment: Maybe you should see this https://www.baeldung.com/junit-noclassdeffounderror